# How do I require the full argument names in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

By default argparse will accept unambiguous prefixes as named arguments. E.g. if I have an argument `--arg1`, argparse will accept `--ar` (if I have another argument with `--ar` prefix it would complain). I want to force argparse to require the full argument name and not just prefixes - that is, only `--arg1` would work in my example - `--ar` would fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using python 3.5 onwards, you can use:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
```

Before that, there is no documented way of doing it. Unless you make your own hacks for it.